# fetch the current page value in st-table

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to add serial numbers to my table. But when I move on to next page the sequence starts from 1 again instead of continuing from the previous value. I want to fetch the currentPage value so that {{ ($index + 1) + (currentPage - 1) * itemsByPage}} gives me the correct index values.Please help how I can achieve this. Its an angularjs application.
Here is my code.

```
 <tbody>
    //code to display hearders 
     <tr ng-repeat="item in itemsCollection">
              <td>{{ ($index + 1) + (currentPage - 1) * itemsByPage}}</td>
              <td>{{item.name}}</td>
              <td>{{item.age}}</td>
     </tr>
    </tbody>
     <tfoot>
            <tr>
              <td colspan="12">
                <div class="text-center" st-pagination="" st-item-by-page="itemsByPage" 
st-template="app/templates/pagination.html" colspan="4"
                ></div>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tfoot>
```

Comment: You need to show how you calculate current page in your controller. Storing the page number as a url param would make sense if you aren’t doing that. Showing your controller would help dissect the problem.

Comment: I'm using st-pagination directive of st-table bower component for pagination. currentPage is a property of st-pagination.